# Save a list of DataFrames in a callable 2D format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to apply some functions on a list of csv files in a folder. The first step goes pretty well:

```
files = os.listdir(os.path.join(WD,'Data/'))
file_path = os.path.join(WD, 'Data')
data_file = glob.glob(file_path + "/*.dat")

result = map(readfile, data_file)
```

readfile is a user-defined function for reading csv files with the same format to apply some changes. But As I try to apply another function to "result", I will get the warning:

```
csvs_result = map(format_data, result)
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, DF-rows, DF-columns)
```

format_data is another user defined function. I know that I am calling from a list but how can I access each element of the list separately to apply other functions?
I have tried to loop over the list and call the ith element, but I am still having a 3D shape and not the 2D data frame.
I am an R programmer and pretty new to Python. In R llapply function will do the same, but the resulting list is still accessible.

below are the two functions I mentioned:

```
def readfile(data_file):
    """From within another python script this command will modify a csv file.
    result is x which is the modified csv file

    Keyword arguments:
    filename -- csv filename
    extra -- colnames, data type and skipping extra rows
    NA -- leading and trainling NA will be removed and NA will be replaced by np.nan
    """

    x_file = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=4, header=None, engine='python', skipinitialspace = True,
                         usecols=[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16],
                         names=['TIMESTAMP', 'ggautc', 'ggalatitude', 'ggalongitude', 'WindSpeed',
                                'WindDirection', 'CH4', 'CO2', 'CompassDir'],
                         dtype={'TIMESTAMP': 'string', 'WindSpeed': 'string'}).replace('"', '', regex=True)
    #, sep = ',', index_col=False, header=None, engine='python',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    x_file['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(x_file['TIMESTAMP'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    x_file.replace({'NA': np.nan}, inplace=True)
    x_file = x_file.loc[x_file.first_valid_index():x_file.last_valid_index()]
    return [x_file]
```

and this is the complete trace:

```
PREPROCESSING
Directory /Preprocessed already exist
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/afshan/Desktop/Company/Scripts/preprocessing.py", line 31, in <module>
    from launcher import WD

  File "/Users/afshan/Desktop/Company/Scripts/launcher.py", line 57, in <module>
    import preprocessing

  File "/Users/afshan/Desktop/company/Scripts/preprocessing.py", line 393, in <module>
    n = len(list(result))

  File "/Users/afshan/Desktop/company/Scripts/preprocessing.py", line 168, in format_data
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 523, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 190, in init_ndarray
    values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 324, in _prep_ndarray
    raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")

ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, nrow, ncol)
```

Update:
It was a mistake I made on returning a dataframe as a list a and save it in a list as well! So basically I had a list of listed dataframe which makes every element of the list a 3D! Thanks to @PierreD it was solved!

Comment: maybe share a snippet of one of the csv files, along with the user defined functions. something small, so we can see what is going on internally.At face value, it seems that you may have to iterate through your `result` mapping.

Comment: `map` just creates a lazy iterator. It doesn't iterate until needed. You didn't copy the stack trace: could it be that the first step (`readfile`) is at fault already?  Can you get a `list(islice(result, 10))`?

Comment: @sammywemmy I am afraid I can not share the data it is quiet sensitive but I added the function readfile I had in my code. My file is just a simple data file and this function is working since I can see the result. Yes I want to be able to iterate through the result again to apply more functions.

Comment: @PierreD The first function is working I used the list(islice(result, 10)) or even with a simple print I can see the dataframes. 77044 2020-09-27 18:11:33.500    1137.2  ...  384.4250        50.8
77045 2020-09-27 18:11:34.000    1137.6  ...  383.8498        50.8
77046 2020-09-27 18:11:34.500    1138.2  ...  383.8498          51
77047 2020-09-27 18:11:35.000    1138.6  ...  382.8932          51
[77049 rows x 9 columns]]]
It is just I can not iterate over these again. I even tried a simple for loop but still the created list of dataframes is not iteratable...

Comment: but the stack trace says "`n = len(list(result))`" (3rd from the top). In any case, why do you `return [x_file]` instead of `return x_file`?

Comment: @PierreD Oh! I think this was the problem! I was returning it as a listed data frame and that's why it was 3D! This is code migration from R and I think I simply made a mistake by return(x_file) to return [x_file]! I will update my final solution shortly if this works...Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readfile` function seems to return a list of one single DataFrame. Then `map` would return `[[df0], [df1], ...]`. Probably not what you expect.

Instead, make sure that `readfile` returns just one DataFrame, not a list:

```py
def readfile(...):
    ...
    return x_file
```

FWIW, we often use the following construct to read many csv files while reducing IO wait times:

```py
with ThreadPoolExecutor(...) as pool:
    frames = list(pool.map(reader, file_list))

# other treatment on individual frames (including filtering if needed,
# can occur here

# ...

# then
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

You can also do it as your example using a single thread:

```py
frames = list(map(reader, file_list))
# optional treatment / filtering
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: I want to. have that list like [[df0], [df1], ...] but the problem is that I can not access these data frames the come out as a 3D form Is there a way not to concatenate data frames and keep them separately? I have different timings in each data frame and there might be a day or hours time difference.

Comment: I still don't see the need for a list of list-of-one dataframes. You can keep the list `[df0, df1, ...]` if you prefer.

Comment: That was my mistake for putting the data frame result in a list! I think it is working now with no problem I just removed the [ ] from the readfile function return part! Thanks!